# How to use colorScheme properties on NativeBase Button but with different color level

Tags: react-native, button, native-base

Is there any way to use colorScheme properties on Button but with different color level. Right now level 500 is the only available and I can't use black / white color

Answer (score 4):

If you need a specific level or color, the recommended approach is to simply use bg e.g. bg="primary.300". Also, bg="black" | "white" will work.

Comment: Here is an example of what  Gaurav suggested

<Button bg="#1c658c" onPress={handlePressOnSignIn}>Sign in</Button>